# Docker container cannot reach other services for a few seconds

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a docker swarm node running a set of docker services connected by a overlay network. When needed I dynamically add another docker node via terraform . It'll be a separate ec2 instance setup and connected as a worker node to the existing swarm network.

I'll run a container from my manager and the running container needs to talk to the existing services in manager node. For eg: Connecting to postgres service and running few queries.

```
docker -H <node ip> run --network <overlay network where services are running> <some image> <command>
```

The script running in the container fails with "Name or service not known" error. I tried to manually ping by bashing into the container and ping succeeds after some 4 or 5 seconds. I tried this hundreds of times and I always get the same issue. Also, it doesn't matter when the node is joined to the swarm. Every time I run the above command, I face the same issue.

Also, I don't have control over what script is run in the container so I cannot add retries.

One more thing. Sometimes, some services can be reached immediately. For eg., Postgres will fail. But another service exposing rest end points can be reached. But it's not always the case.

I was able to reproduce this issue with a bunch of test services:

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create a docker swarm and add another machine as a worker node to
   docker swarm
2. Create a overlay network in node 1 `docker network create -d overlay --attachable platform`
3. Create services in node 1 `for i in {1..25} do   docker service create --network platform -p :80 --name "service-${i}"
   dockerbogo/docker-nginx-hello-world done`
4. Create a task from node 1 to be run in node 2 `docker -H 10.128.0.3:2376 run --rm --network platform centos ping service-1`

Docker daemon logs: https://pastebin.com/65Lihp8v

Any help?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Startup order is not the issue because services will be already running. Consider this worker node as dynamically added to perform a single task.

Comment: It sounds like startup ordering to me. The program in the container will have to take a few seconds to start, even if the same program is already running in another container, because it's a different instance.

Comment: It's just a python script querying the database or some service for some data.

Comment: In step 4, you're creating a standalone container, not a task that belongs to the swarm or 
a service, although having the same network attached should make service discovery work. I would suggest trying to create a service instead of standalone container in step 4 but with a placement constraint set to your new worker node. Also, adding a delay before the program runs might solve your problem because I'm guessing that container took time to setup its networking and it could be a cause of not resolving the service immediately

Comment: @ahasbini I tried a service as well with placement constraints. Even a simple service with command with ping as command like in step 4 fails on the first run. The issue for me (in the software I'm working on) is I don't have control over what script is running in the container so adding a delay will be difficult for my case. It looks like a race condition in docker to me.